# select products with categories include all parents

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables in my database:

```
create table category (id_category integer, name_category text, parent_id integer);
create table product (id_product integer, name_product text, id_category integer, description text);

insert into category
        values
        (1, 'Category A', null),
        (2, 'Category B', null),
        (3, 'Category C', null),
        (4, 'Category D', null),
        (5, 'Subcategory Of 1', 1),
        (6, 'Subcategory Of 5', 5),
        (7, 'Subcategory Of 5', 5),
        (8, 'Subcategory of D', 4)
        ;

insert into product
        values
        (1, 'Product One', 5, 'Our first product'),
        (2, 'Product Two', 6, 'Our second product'),
        (3, 'Product three', 6, 'Our third product'),
        (4, 'Product four', 6, 'Our 4th product'),
        (5, 'Product five', 7, 'Our 5th product'),
        (6, 'Product six', 8, 'The even better one');
```

How can I return like this:

```
id_category| name_product | id_product    |               
-----------+--------------+---------------+
         1 | Product One  |             1 |
         1 | Product Two  |             2 |
         1 | product three|             3 |
         1 | Product four |             4 |
         1 | Product five |             5 |
```

What's the best way to do this ?

later i will take id_category instance variable id_category = 1 from php
can i use sql query or have to use php function?

I want to create like some e-commerce, there they have several stratified categories (tree), when customers click parent categories the output all product with parents

forgive me a bad question, because i use google translate

Comment: Do you want to ask only the right query to do this? Or the php process complete with the query to fetch the data?

Comment: only query sql I need

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQL query like this: `SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_category = 1`

You see the WHERE statement? This is where you can set what you want to filter.

Comment: I want to create like some e-commerce, there they have several stratified categories (tree), when customers click parent categories the output all product with parents

Comment: @jokowi the query I gave you is what you need, of course with little edit. If you're not familiar enough with PHP I recommend you to read some articles how to fetch data from SQL with PHP.

Comment: I think you are misunderstood, id_category is taken from table categories, of course must use the join statement but I want the output from child also come